# Add text to specific line without removing the exist line in php

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to add only last name if first name is same

data.txt

```
Alice Sandy
Alice Nanami
James Watt
Alice Monica
Johann Gauss
```

to result.txt

```
Alice Sandy Nanami Monica
James Watt
Johann Gauss
```

I try with this code

```php
$resultFile = "result.txt";
$search     = "Alice";
$lineNumber = false;
if ($handle = fopen($result, "r")) {
    $count = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== FALSE and !$lineNumber) {
        $count++;
        $lineNumber = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? $count : $lineNumber;
        $isExist = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? "yup" : "no";
    }
fclose($handle);
}
if($isExist=="yup"){
    $lines = file($resultFile);
    $lines[$lineNumber] = $lines[$lineNumber].' '.$lastName;
    file_put_contents($result, implode('', $lines));
}else{
    $fullName = $firstName.' '.$lastName;
    $fileOpen = fopen($result, "a");
    fwrite($fileOpen,$fullName);
    fclose($fileOpen);
    $addBreaker = "\n";
    $splResult = new SplFileObject($resultFile, 'a');
    $splResult->fwrite($addBreaker);
}
```

But it give error offset (I'm using PHP 7) and the result is untidy

```
Alice Sandy Nanami
 Monica
James Watt

Johan Gauss
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file()` to collect the file contents as an array of lines. My snippet starts from there with `$lines`.

Iterate the array and makes each line modifiable by reference. (`&`)

Locate the first occurring needle match that not only exists in the line but matches the whole first word so that you don't get false-positive matching.

Then declare the first match as a reference variable (`=&`) and continue iterating the array.  Any subsequent matches will have the delimiting space and second word appended to the reference variable.  Then immediate unset the line to be purged from the document.

When done, re-implode the data and stuff the content into the result file.

This is clean, readable, and only needs one loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hOoYV))

```
// $lines = file('result.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$lines = [
    'Alice Sandy',
    'Alice Nanami',
    'James Watt',
    'Alice Monica',
    'Johann Gauss',
    'Cooper Alice',
];

$needle = 'Alice';
foreach($lines as $index => &$line) {
    if ($needle === strstr($line, ' ', true)) { // check whole first word
        if (!isset($firstOccurrence)) {
            $firstOccurrence =& $line;
        } else {
            $firstOccurrence .= strstr($line, ' ');
            unset($lines[$index]);
        }
    }
}
var_export($lines);
// file_put_contents('result.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Alice Sandy Nanami Monica',
  2 => 'James Watt',
  4 => 'Johann Gauss',
  5 => 'Cooper Alice',
)
```

P.s  if you want to know if any rows were changed you could check if the original array is `===` the new array after looping, or you could just use a boolean flag variable in the `else` condition.

Comment: That is inefficient way to replace only `Alice` records. And saying it needs only one loop is not entirely true, because `file()` is also internally looping over lines. @Palguno Wicaksono, shame on you removing comments.

Comment: I will not be revenge DVing your answer although it is ignoring the OP requirement to search for a specific needle.

Comment: It's not revenge downvote. I'm not playing such way and don't care much about rep. Your solution is just not good. Iterating over all names would require 2 loops.

Comment: There is nothing DV-worthy about my answer.  In other words, there is nothing to improve.  This is non-beneficial voting on your behalf, but I know you cannot reverse your vote anymore.  I would certainly use my snippet in one of my own projects because it is clear, direct, keeps variable declarations to a minimum, and there is one loop which performs all of the mutations.  When the loop is finished the data is ready to be written back to file.  I cannot say the same of your snippet.  Your snippet will be needlessly imploding lots of single-element arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Another apporach instead of replacing lines would be save every line to an array and then iterate over array and save to the new file. You can also use the same file as an `$outputFile`.

```
$inputFile = 'names.txt';
$outputFile = 'result.txt';

$names = [];

if ($handle = fopen($inputFile, "r")) {
    $count = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== FALSE) {
        $count++;
        $lineNames = explode(' ', $line);
        $names[$lineNames[0]][] = trim($lineNames[1]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$handle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
foreach ($names as $firstName => $lastNames) {
    fwrite($handle, $firstName . ' ' . implode(' ', $lastNames) . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Two additional notes:

1. Don't use string as boolean value.

   $isExist = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? "yup" : "no";

Use just following condition. It's enough

```
$isExist = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE)
```

2. If you read lines from file you copy also new lines char, although you can't see them quite well in the output. You should trim all whitespace characters before inserting/replacing etc. to avoid old structure of file.